# Storing one to many relation in database - Array or one to many relation?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, graph

When we store a one to many association in a database, which is a better approach. One - Many mapping in a table or storing the many part as an array. I'm specific to postgres database (constraint)

For example: If we define the relationship as follows

```
a   b
1 - 2
1 - 3
1 - 6
2 - 3 
2 - 4
3 - 5
3 - 6
```

Here, the one part is a and the many part is b (Primary key being a, b)

The same thing can be stored as an array as (similar to an adjacency list).

```
1 - {2,3,6}
2 - {3,4}
3 - {5,6}
```

Which of this is more efficient. I may have to do some operations on this such as transitive closure etc. and, the graph may be really huge.

A practical example of the above may be something like connections of a particular profile (LinkedIn connections), or any social graph scenario

Comment: `Which of this is more efficient` Is the wrong question. Database modeelling is primarily concerned with correctness. Efficiency comes later (but is often a side-effect of correctness)

Answer (score 0):

In your example the relationship is many to many, not one to many. Multiple `a` records can be associated with one `b` and multiple `b` records can be associated with one `a`. As such, the correct normalized form is a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Hypothetically, imagine this DB relationship represents one profile "liking" another profile in a social media context. In that case you may want to store additional information; a timestamp of when the "like" was initiated, the degree to which the profiled shruged/liked/loved the other profile, etc. It then becomes apparent that in the array implementation there is nowhere to store this additional data. You need a join table so that each "like" can have its own metadata.

Here is the structure I would recommend:

```
PK   A   B
100  1 - 2
200  1 - 3
300  1 - 6
400  2 - 3 
500  2 - 4
600  3 - 5
700  3 - 6
```

Where PK is an auto generated PK, hopefully from a sequence, and `A, B` are constrained by a unique index. This structure is future proof for eventually dropping the unique index on `A, B`, a headache I've had to deal with occasionally.